# If I say 'I wish the world full of love', does it sound awkward?

Tags: grammar, phrases

I try to say

"We wish the world 
full of love, not hatred
full of mercy, not discrimination
full of possibility and hope, not exclusion"

during the podium speech, and I am not sure if this sounds awkward for the native.

Is it grammatically wrong? Or does it sound unnatural?

Comment: Please look up how to form a sentence with wish. You are missing a verb after wish. Clue: I wish this were easier but it isn't.

Comment: This kind of construction works when you address yourself to people, as in: *We wish the couple lots of happiness. We wish our children health, wealth and success.*

Comment: @RonaldSole yes, exactly. Otherwise, We want the world to be full of love etc. OR: We wish the world were full of love, etc. In a speech from a podium, either of those would work.

Comment: @Lambie: Your remarks would be relevant if this were not a "podium speech" where a more elevated style is not only permissible but often expected.  It is perfectly acceptable to drop **to be** there.

Comment: KSM - You'd be better off waiting before accepting an answer. You might get better feedback. I suggest reading [_Not So Fast!_ on meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).

Comment: @ Tᴚoɯɐuo Fyi, I have actually written speeches for people. And I would never use "We wish the world to be a place of [whatever]. That use of "to be" is awkward here. In a fairy tale or old-fashioned speech: ***But, said the Queen, "We wish the Prince to be our ruler now."***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be trying to say:

We wish the world to be (a place) full of love not hatred, full of mercy not discrimination, full of possibility and hope not exclusion.

Here is how the rhythms would go if those words were spoken by a native speaker:

*We wish the world full of love ... not hatred

full of mercy ... not discrimination

full of possibility and hope ... not exclusion*

P.S. The commenters think you should make your podium speech  sound more conversational.  My advice here accepts the formality of your original, and points out that your phrasing is oratorical in style in its omission of **to be**. It is perfectly grammatical to say

`We wish it (to be) {adjectival complement}`

> We wish it understood.
>
> We wish it known.
>
> We wish the world full of love...

but such phrasing is not in contemporary idiom but in an older oratorical style.  While such style is not inappropriate for a formal speech when you're aiming for an "elevated" somewhat literary tone that  invokes long tradition—and judging from the parallelism of your clauses, that does seem what you might be going for—if you were trying to speak in a contemporary neutral idiom, it might go something like this:

> We truly want the world to be full of love ... not hatred
>
> We want very much for the world to be full of love ... not hatred

Comment: Yes that was what I intended to say. Um, so then If I apply the rhythm you told me, is it good enough to make that sentence sound natural? Or do I need to change something, like grammatical mistake?

Comment: Those rhythms are how a native speaker would say these parallel clauses. Your punctuation was not good but the grammar was good.  The style is oratorical but not unnatural.

Comment: You have dropped the words **to be**. Dropping them is certainly OK in a speech in "elevated" style. In conversation most people would say "We wish the world to be full of love...not hatred".

Comment: Sorry, but the most likely thing a native speaker would say: I wish the world were a better place, and not: I wish the world to be a better place. However: We wish you happy birthday. We wish you a happy new year.

Comment: @Lambie: Most likely *within the constraints of that specific sentence*. How's the sun out there in left field?

Comment: There are no constraints. The OP didn't get the grammar and to not give him the verbs actually used after wish is not helpful. It is most unlikely that anyone would say "We wish the world to be a better place" in a speech. "We want the world to be a better place." is much more speech-like.

Comment: @Lambie:  I think OP *did* get the grammar. I wrote "in a speech" not "in speech". And I did indeed give him the words he had omitted. You are not a careful reader.  And just because you do not use the word **wish** doesn't mean that it is unnatural across the English-speaking world, especially in a speech. You'd probably say "really want" in many contexts but not in a formal speech.

Comment: Interesting. I think the phrasing could be improved, but it need not be with a verb. I might suggest: _We wish **for a** world full of love, not hatred; full of mercy, not discrimination_.

Comment: @ Tᴚoɯɐuo For me: "We wish the world to be (a place) full of love" sounds very corny and awkward in English. "We want a world filled with love" etc. OR "We wish the world were filled with love". Both those are formal.  I have a feeling the OP doesn't really mean **wish** here, but rather **want**. I'm commenting on both in a speech and in speech.

Comment: @Lambie: I guess it depends on how familiar or unfamiliar you are with the language as it existed in former times.  I don't think anyone who has read widely from the works of centuries past would find anything "awkward" at all with OP's sentence. It seems to me to have a certain grace.  "Corny", on the other hand', is in the eye of the beholder, and one's man's corny is another man's meat and potatoes.